# A problem of Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is : 
In a market survey,a manufacturer obtained the following data :

```
Did you use our brand?         Percentage answering yes        

1. April                               59
2. May                                 62
3. June                                62
4. April and May                       35
5. May and June                        33
6. April and June                      31
7. April,May and June                  22

Is this correct?                           

That is the question.Now I don't really understand how to determine yes or not.
Please help me.
```

Comment: How is this a problem of set theory?

Comment: I guess that it is an application of inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: This problem is included in set theory chapter,that's what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct, and we can see this using only statements 1, 2, and 4.

Let A = # of people who responded to the survey in April,
    M = # of people who responded to the survey in May.

Then A + M = total # of people who responded in April and May.

By (1), (0.59)*A = # of people who answered yes in April and by (2), (0.62)*M = # of people who answered yes in May.

If we add these values, we get # of people who answered yes in April and May, which by (4) is equal to (0.35)*(A + M)

So we get the equation
(0.59)*A + (0.62)*M = (0.35)*(A + M)

Solve for A and get A = -(0.27/0.24)*M

This suggests that A = M = 0, or that one of A and M is negative. Both of these cases are impossible for a survey of people, for # of people is a strictly positive quantity.